# Event Management - notify participant on receiption of payment or on cancellation

Tags: civievent

I am setting up an event using CiviEvent.

People can register and have to transfer the event fee.

What do I need to to that people get a one time notification if the payment is received (manual status change to "transfer received") or if their registration is canceled (for example to modify it).

I am aware of the automatic reminders but I did not found how to configure them that the message is sent just at the day of the status change and only at that day.

I am using CiviCRM 5.2.0 on Wordpress 4.9.6.

Thanks,

Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one of the two ways

1. When you edit a participant you get an option to send confirmation email. Ticking the checkbox and saving the form will send email to contact.

[image]

2. Other option is to send reminder for particular participant status. Navigate to Administer >> Communications >> Schedule Reminders. On Add reminder form select entity as either Event Name or Event type and then select Event Name/Event Type and then Participant status with other fields.

[image]

> Note: Make sure Schedule reminder schedule job is enabled if you
>   sending it via schedule reminder. But i would prefer to use method 1
>   as it is most convenient and easy.

HTH

Pradeep